# Laravel 5.4 auth middleware overrides redirectTo method issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm working with the Laravel Auth scaffold. Inside my `LoginController.php` file I have my `redirectTo` method. I wan't it so that it has a conditional redirect. However, every time I test the login route, the route goes to `/home` instead of the route specified inside my conditional.

LoginController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\Role;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void=
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->isEmployer()){
          return '/employer';
        }
          
        return '/home';  
        
    }

}
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

web.php

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/employer', 'EmployerController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I wrote a `dd()` function inside my `if` statement and it does work. The problem is the redirect always goes to `/home` no matter what.

I don't get the point of having the `redirectTo` method when the `guest` auth middleware will always override that function?

How would I be able to depend on this redirect method without having the middleware override that method?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your web.php file?

Comment: I've just added it.

Comment: Is there any middlewares act when you access the EmployerController@index() function?

Comment: No, I don't have any middlewares on that function at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware according to your conditions. Like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if(Auth::guard($guard)->user()->isEmployer())
            {
               return redirect('/employer');

             } else return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

The `redirectTo` method is used for redirecting the user after successful login/register. But middlewares have a different function they always analyse requests before(or after) entering(or leaving) the controller.

I think you already know this, the point you're missing is that; If you want to redirect the user after a successful login you must put the logic inside `redirectTo` method or at least mention the route to redirect using the `redirectTo` attribute available in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.Other ways laravel redirects you to default `/home` route.
This only happens when the user submits the login form, If you want to redirect your already signed in user to a different location (here route `/employer` ) you have to define it using the middleware.